# If database result exists, do this, else, do that

Tags: php, database, if-statement, pdo

I am checking a database to see if there is a data match. If there is, output some HTML, if not, output different HTML.

For some reason, this query is not working. The data in the database does provide a match, but the first HTML is not being output.

I have a feeling it has something to do with me using 'FALSE'... should I be doing this differently?

```
<?php

// Check current favourite status
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_favourites WHERE user_id = :who AND favourite_id = :usernum AND favourite_active = '1' LIMIT 1";

$q   = $conn->prepare($sql); // the default way of PDO to manage errors is quite the same as `or die()` so no need for that
$q->bindValue(':who',$who,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$q->bindValue(':usernum',$usernum,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$q->execute();

if($r = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)!== false)
{
    echo "<div id=\"favourite\" class=\"favouriteOptionActive\" onclick=\"loadXMLDoc('indexFavourite')\">Selected as favourite</div>";
}       
else
{
    echo "<div id=\"favourite\" class=\"favouriteOption\" onclick=\"loadXMLDoc('indexFavourite')\">Add me as a favourite</div>";
}

?>
```

Comment: just get rid of this FALSE. along with !==

Comment: `if($r = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)!== false)` should really be `if(($r = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) !== false)`

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan: `false` and `FALSE` both work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing `SELECT *` do `SELECT COUNT(*)` since you aren't actually using any of the data queried.

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_favourites WHERE user_id = :who AND favourite_id = :usernum AND favourite_active = '1' LIMIT 1";
$q   = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->bindValue(':who',$who,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$q->bindValue(':usernum',$usernum,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$q->execute();
$found = $q->fetchColumn();

if ($found > 0) {
    // Do stuff
}
else {
    // Do other stuff
}
```

Also note that your comment `the default way of PDO to manage errors is quite the same as or die() so no need for that` is false. The default way PDO handles errors is [silently](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php). If you want either of the other two error modes, you need to set them yourself.

Comment: This all looks very nice, but it's still not working. How frustrating! The information is 100% in the database too.

Comment: @ElaineAdams please let me know what you mean by "not working". What does `var_dump($found);` output?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT 1 FROM tbl_favourites WHERE user_id = ? AND favourite_id = ? 
        AND favourite_active = 1 LIMIT 1";
$q   = $conn->prepare($sql); 
$q->execute([$who, $usernum]);
$exists = $q->fetchColumn();
?>
<div id="favourite" class="favouriteOption<? if ($exists): ?>Active<? endif ?>" onclick="loadXMLDoc('indexFavourite')">
<? if ($exists): ?>
    Selected as favourite
<? else: ?> 
    Add me as a favourite
<? endif ?>
</div>
```